# Where are the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, kernel, visual-studio-2019

I had to reinstall Visual Studio 2019 because of a hard drive incident. I was able to download it apply the license and all my projects compile and run as before, except my driver project. It now complains that the platform toolset WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 cannot be found.

I looked everywhere for the installer for it, but my searches keep pointing me off to Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022. I don't want to upgrade to Windows 11 or Visual Studio 2022.

Where can I find the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools for Windows 10 and VS 2019?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure when you install Visual Studio that you selected "Desktop development with C++" as one of the tools/dev resources to install along with it.

After Visual Studio with the above tool is installed, you need the WDK (Windows Developer Kit). The official download links for the WDK for various Windows versions are located on [this Microsoft Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#step-2-install-the-wdk).

For example (this link may change or die over time), the official download link for Windows 10 build 2004 through build 22H2 is https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128854